# Pattern Matching on Function

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have a function, `dir_con :: (Int -> Dir)`

I want to pattern match to find which specific constructor dir_con is. The data type is:

```
data Dir = Define Int
         | Equals Int 
         | Data Int  
         | LCset Int
         | NoArg Int
```

So, dir_con will either be Define, Equals etc. It is passed to a function and I want to pattern match like so:

```
case dir_con of
    NoArg -> Do something specific
    _     -> Do something for the rest
```

The compiler doesn't like that. Error message is `Couldn't match expected type 'Int -> Dir' with actual type 'Dir'`.

Surely `NoArg` is a constructor of type `(Int -> Dir)`? Does Haskell not allow this type of pattern match? I have to do this because the `Dir` constructors come from a map. Is there a suggestion on how I can treat `NoArg` differently?

Comment: You may want to refactor your datatype to move the current constuctors to an enumeration, e.g. something like `data Dir = Dir DirType Int; data DirType = Define | Equals | Data | LCset | NoArg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pattern match on functions. A value of type `Dir` is built by applying one of several constructors, but `dir_con` is a function of type `Int -> Dir`.

You probably want to apply the function before pattern matching:

```
case dir_con 7 of  -- `7` is just an arbitrary value I'm passing
  NoArg _ -> ...
  _       -> ...
```

In addition, you have to match on the argument of the `NoArg` constructor as well, or else you'll get another type error after adding the argument to `dir_con`.

In your concrete situation, you'll most likely not want to pass a literal integer, but perhaps an argument you're getting from elsewhere:

```
myfun n = ... case dir_con n of
                NoArg _ -> ...
                _       -> ...
```

Comment: A simple and elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways:

```
case dir_con of
    NoArg _ -> Do something specific
    _     -> Do something for the rest
```

You're matching the /value/ not the constructor function.

Or, usingr record syntax:

```
case dir_con of
    NoArg {} -> Do something specific
    _     -> Do something for the rest
```

which is good hygiene, as it is neutral with respect to the number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

If all your constructors are of type `Int -> Dir`, then I would suggest the same as @hammar: make the constructor type an enumeration:

```
data DirType = Define | Equals | Data | LCset | NoArg

data Dir = Dir DirType Int
```

Then you can probably refactor whatever needs to know what constructor it is to use a value of `DirType` there instead.

The essential problem with trying to determine what constructor `dir_con :: Int -> Dir` is is that not everything of that type is a constructor.  For exampe:

```
dispatch :: Int -> Dir
dispatch 0 = Define 0
dispatch 1 = Equals 1
dispatch n = NoArg n
```

There is no good answer that you can get for "which constructor" `dispatch` is.

If `Dir` were parametric

```
data Dir a = Define a | Equals a | Data a | LCset a | NoArg a
```

then there is a type of `Dir` constructors; namely `forall a. a -> Dir a` (you need the `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` extension to work with such types).  Such a type disallows shenanigans like `dispatch` which inspects its argument.  So if you have:

```
dir_con :: forall a. a -> Dir a
```

then you can inspect its constructor by passing it a trivial value

```
case dir_con () of
    ...
```

Even though you only ever *practically* use a `Dir Int`, the polymorphism allows you to be more descriptive with your types.